# How do I organize my pure functions with my monadic actions idiomatically

Tags: haskell, monads, function-composition

I've decided today is the day I fix some of my pure functions that are unnecessarily running in a monadic action. Here's what I have.

```
flagWorkDays :: [C.Day] -> Handler [WorkDay] 
flagWorkDays dayList =
   flagWeekEnds dayList >>=
   flagHolidays >>=
   flagScheduled >>=
   flagASAP >>=
   toWorkDays
```

Here is flagWeekEnds, as of now.

```
flagWeekEnds :: [C.Day] -> Handler [(C.Day,Availability)]
flagWeekEnds dayList = do
   let yepNope = Prelude.map isWorkDay dayList
       availability = Prelude.map flagAvailability yepNope
   return $ Prelude.zip dayList availability
```

`flagHolidays` follows a similar pattern. `toWorkDays` just changes one type to another, and is a pure function.

`flagScheduled`, and `flagASAP` are monadic actions. I am not sure how to combine the monadic actions with the pure functions idiomatically in `flagWorkDays`. Could someone help me fix `flagWorkDays`, assuming `flagWeekEnds` and `flagHolidays` have been made pure?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let's take a step back for a moment. You have two types of functions, some pure with types of the form `a -> b`, and some monadic of type `a -> m b`.

To avoid confusion, let's also stick with right-to-left composition. If you prefer to read left-to-right,  just reverse the order of the functions and replace `(<=<)` with `(>=>)`, and `(.)` with `(>>>)` from `Control.Arrow`.

There are then four possibilities for how these can be composed.

1. **Pure then pure.** Use regular function composition `(.)`.

   ```
    g :: a -> b
    f :: b -> c
    f . g :: a -> c
   ```
2. **Pure then monadic**. Also use `(.)`.

   ```
    g :: a -> b
    f :: b -> m c
    f . g :: a -> m c
   ```
3. **Monadic then monadic**. Use kleisli composition `(<=<)`.

   ```
    g :: a -> m b
    f :: b -> m c
    f <=< g :: a -> m c
   ```
4. **Monadic then pure**. Use `fmap` on the pure function and  `(.)` to compose.

   ```
    g :: a -> m b
    f :: b -> c
    fmap f . g :: a -> m c
   ```

Ignoring the specifics of the types involved, your functions are:

```
flagWeekEnds :: a -> b
flagHolidays :: b -> c
flagScheduled :: c -> m d
flagASAP :: d -> m e
toWorkDays :: e -> f
```

Let's go from the top. `flagWeekEnds` and `flagHolidays` are both pure. Case 1.

```
flagHolidays . flagWeekEnds
  :: a -> c
```

This is pure. Next up is `flagScheduled`, which is monadic. Case 2.

```
flagScheduled . flagHolidays . flagWeekEnds
  :: a -> m d
```

Next is `flagASAP`, now we have two monadic functions. Case 3.

```
flagASAP <=< flagScheduled . flagHolidays . flagWeekEnds
  :: a -> m e
```

And finally, we have the pure function `toWorkDays`. Case 4.

```
fmap toWorkDays . flagASAP <=< flagScheduled . flagHolidays . flagWeekEnds
  :: a -> m f
```

And we're done.

Answer (score 4):

It's not very difficult. You basically just replace `(>>=)` by `(.)` and flip the operands order. `do` syntax may help to clarify. I also made the example pointfree using the Kleisli combinator (fish) `(<=<) :: (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c`, that is essentially `(.)` for monads.

```
import Control.Monad

flagWorkDays :: [C.Day] -> Handler [WorkDay] 
flagWorkDays =
  fmap toWorkDays . flagASAP <=< flagScheduled . flagHolidays . flagWeekEnds
```

Comment: @Tarrasch pointless'd away. I forgot to remove the extra parameter

Comment: Is there an usual name / predefined function for `flip (.)`? I'm kinda sad that the transformation here had to put things backwards

Comment: @missingno I've yet to see one

Comment: @missingno `>>>` from Control.Arrow? (Though it has a more general type.)

Answer (score 4):

To fill in FUZxxl's answer, let's pureify `flagWeekEnds`:

```
flagWeekEnds :: [C.Day] -> [(C.Day,Availability)]
flagWeekEnds days = days `zip` map (flagAvailability . isWorkDay) days
```

You often put an "s" after variable names (`day` -> `days`) when its a list (as you do with plural in English).